# Picking values dynamically from variables in R

Tags: r, variables, dynamic-variables

I have 10 variables declared as numeric vectors in R.
They are like

```
 A1 = {10,12,13,14.....}
 A2 = {15,18,19,20.....}
 A3 = {99,88,76,90,....}
```

and they continue till A10.

Now I want to pick the values of these variables using a for loop and assign them to a variable names created dynamically. I can use assign to create dynamic variables but I am not able to pick these values.

So I want to pick values like

```
x = A&i # Or Something that picks the value of vector using for loop
```

I have tried paste() but to no success.

```
assign(paste("highrange",i,sep=""),(paste("A",i,sep="")-3*paste(A,i,sep="")))
```

Comment: Could you please show what a sample output should be on a smaller subset?

Comment: Also please include the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Also read about [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks. Will be more careful next time while asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `get()`:

```
#data
A1 = c(10,12,13,14)
A2 = c(15,18,19,20)

#index
An <- 1
Aix <- 2

#assign
assign("myVar", get(paste0("A", An))[Aix])

#result
myVar
# [1] 12
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.